# search for messages where two fields have the same value

Tags: graylog

I am trying to compare two fields a tmestamp and last changed which are both unix timestamps. If they are both the same show me those results of messages found
Following the example in the post below I did this
https://community.graylog.org/t/make-search-string-with-comparison-of-fields-values-field1-field2/1528

```
c_event_last_state_change IS c_event_timestamp
```

However this doesn’t seem to work at all, or doesn’t give me the outcome I am expecting. Is this even possible or is there another way to possibly accomplish this?